# constructing an identifier string for each row in data

Tags: string, r, data.table

I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(a = c(1:3), b = c(2:4))
```

and would like to get this result (in a way that would work with arbitrary number of columns):

```
d[, c := paste0('a_', a, '_b_', b)]
d
#   a b       c
#1: 1 2 a_1_b_2
#2: 2 3 a_2_b_3
#3: 3 4 a_3_b_4
```

The following works, but I'm hoping to find something shorter and more legible.

```
d = data.table(a = c(1:3), b = c(2:4))
d[, c := apply(mapply(paste, names(.SD), .SD, MoreArgs = list(sep = "_")),
               1, paste, collapse = "_")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way, only slightly cleaner:

```
d[, c :=  apply(d, 1, function(x) paste(names(d), x, sep="_", collapse="_")) ]

     a b       c
1: 1 2 a_1_b_2
2: 2 3 a_2_b_3
3: 3 4 a_3_b_4
```

Comment: thanks, that's definitely more legible with less apply's; current R-golf winner :)

Comment: I think `apply` will convert `d` to a matrix. So, there will be copies and less efficiency.

Comment: @Roland, you are correct, this is by no means efficient.  An alternative is to use `by=names(d)`  but then you have to pull the values back in to `paste`, or you have to pull `paste` to the outside of `j`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `do.call('paste')`, but requiring only a single call to `paste`

I will benchmark on a situtation where the columns are integers (as this seems  a more sensible test case

```
N <- 1e4

d <- setnames(as.data.table(replicate(5, sample(N), simplify = FALSE)), letters[seq_len(5)])

f5 <- function(d){
  l <- length(d)
  o <- c(1L, l + 1L) + rep_len(seq_len(l) -1L, 2L * l)
  do.call('paste',c((c(as.list(names(d)),d))[o],sep='_'))}


microbenchmark(f1(d), f2(d),f5(d))
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 f1(d)  41.51040  43.88348  44.60718  45.29426  52.83682   100
 f2(d) 193.94656 207.20362 210.88062 216.31977 252.11668   100
 f5(d)  30.73359  31.80593  32.09787  32.64103  45.68245   100
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid looping through rows, you can use this:

`do.call(paste, c(lapply(names(d), function(n)paste0(n,"_",d[[n]])), sep="_"))`

Benchmarking:

```
N <- 1e4

d <- data.table(a=runif(N),b=runif(N),c=runif(N),d=runif(N),e=runif(N))

f1 <- function(d)
{
    do.call(paste, c(lapply(names(d), function(n)paste0(n,"_",d[[n]])), sep="_"))
}

f2 <- function(d)
{
    apply(d, 1, function(x) paste(names(d), x, sep="_", collapse="_"))
}

require(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1(d), f2(d))
```

Note: `f2` inspired in @Ricardo's answer.

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 f1(d) 195.8832 213.5017 216.3817 225.4292 254.3549   100
 f2(d) 418.3302 442.0676 451.0714 467.5824 567.7051   100
```

Edit note: previous benchmarking with `N <- 1e3` didn't show much difference in times. Thanks again @eddi.

Comment: hmm, I +1'd it because it seemed right, but upon testing, I don't think your `f1` is working as is

Comment: oh ok, you just need to replace `d[,n]` with `d[[n]]`

Comment: in my tests it's actually 2x faster than Ricardo's or agstudy's answers (running the same code as above, and I tried larger N's as well)

Comment: I think this solution is great for someone looking for speed, in this instance I was looking for a shorter expression and this speed difference didn't matter; thanks again

Comment: this constraint is not specified in the question (as I realized it just now), but fwiw I actually ended up using this version instead because I needed to preserve the column types when pasting (my actual computation is more complicated than the OP) and `apply` destroys that information